# send hex value to client side via ruby socket

Tags: ruby, sockets, hex

I am working on creating a socket server . This server is working on hex values.

I am able to establish the connection to the server . But not able to read clients hex values and not able to put hex value to client side.

```
require "socket"


def listenserver (server)
 @buff1 =[160, 124]
 client = server.accept
 puts  "#{client.inspect} is accepted"
 client.print "0x%02x" % @buff1[0]
 client.print"0x%02x" % @buff1[1]
 puts "#{@buff1.inspect}"
 puts "0x%02x" % @buff1[0]
 client.close
 puts "#{client} is gone"
end

server = TCPServer.new('x.x.x.x', 12345)
loop do
 puts "Started TCPServer"
 listenserver(server)

end
```

Comment: plz add the array @buff and a example url you use to test

Comment: the server is private , but main point is when we print hex value , it reaches to client as string . I have updated buff1 arrey ,please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

**What you're looking for is [Array.pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [String.unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack)**

Sample code from the Ruby Docs:

For **Array.pack**:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]  
a.pack("A3A3A3")  
=> "a  b c "
```

and **Sting.unpack**:

```
"\xfe\xff\xfe\xff".unpack('sS')
=> [-2, 65534]

"whole".unpack('xax2aX2aX1aX2a')
=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```